# Should I upgrade the Hardware Enablement Stack? How should I do it?

Tags: release-freya, hardware, kernel, ubuntu

[image]

> **New important security and hardware support update**
>
> WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack ended on 2016-08-04: *http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

I've read that the recently published version of Ubuntu 16.04, which is Ubuntu 14.04.5, comes with a new kernel and X stack in order to support a wider variety of hardware (see here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes and here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/14.04.5).

Since elementary OS freya is based on Ubuntu 14.04: Does anybody know if and when these changes will be implemented in Freya, too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing that they will (but you could do it yourself). But elementary OS Loki is going to be released soon so I think you should wait for it.

In April Ubuntu 16.04 will be released and later Loki will be released

Comment: Sure Loki will be released in the not too distant future. I was just interested if something is planned for the interim

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for these changes to be made within Freya, as the update is being delivered via the update manager. The correct way to upgrade to the Xenial Hardware Enablement Stack via the command line is like this:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial`

Comment: A related question: I manually installed another Kernel (4.2.8) which was the easiest way for me to get elementary OS Freya running on a new Skylake Intel NUC. The stock kernel didn't support the WiFi card and Kernels above 4.2.x caused massive graphic glitches. Support for 4.2.x is over now and I wanted to upgrade to Xenial and the enablement stack as per your method.
I get tons of unmet dependency alerts. Do I have to get back to the 3.13 kernel and then upgrade via wire/ethernet? What would a best practice be? Thanks and cheers from Germany!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure, maybe post another question about your dependency problems?

Comment: For some reason though the command line method (copy+paste) didn't work for me (dependencies), the update prompt "Install" now worked (without any dependency warnings). Very strange.